# Listview selected item to PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, listview, picturebox

I am new with vb and sql, can someone help me Retrieve image when i click my selected items in listview and view it on PictureBox so that i can update the values.

```
     Private Sub lvRegistered_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As 
     EventArgs) Handles lvRegisteredV1.SelectedIndexChanged

  If lvRegisteredV1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
  pbRear.Image = Image.FromFile(lvRegisteredV1.SelectedItems(0).ToString)

  End If
  End Sub
         ------i have tried this but shows an error "An unhandled exception 
 of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
 Additional information: The given path's format is not supported."
```

Comment: I don't see an image or a PictureBox in your code. Where is the code that attempted to retrieve an image? Show you attempt so we can help.

Comment: Database interaction in .Net is usually done with ADO.Net. If haven't seen ADODB in a long time.

Comment: i dont have any codes yet retrieving image from my sql, i have 1 listview  and 3 picturebox

Comment: Is the actual image stored in the database or just the path and file name? What exactly did you store in the `.Tag` property?

Comment: with or without `.Tag` gives the error..  and actual `image` is saved in my database

Comment: Did you put anything in the `.Tag` property?

Comment: did not. and this error shows up `The given path's format is not supported`

Comment: What is your database. Sql Server, Access, MySql or something else? Also what is the exact datatype of the picture field in the database.

Comment: Sql, datatype: `image`

Comment: Again, what is the database? Microsoft Sql Server, MySql, Sqlite? Just Sql doesn't tell me which Sql it is. It makes a difference.

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

You made a good choice of the `.Tag` property. It can hold any type of object. I would guess you are filling your list view in a loop using a DataReader. You are creating a new list view item on each iteration. This `ListViewItem` is where you would fill the .Tag property with the raw data. Then when the item is selected you retrieve the raw data convert it to a Byte array and place it in a MemoryStream. The `.Image` property is then filled from the stream.

Just to simplify, I used a single record and a TextBox.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    RetrieveImage()
    Using MS As New MemoryStream(CType(txtName.Tag, Byte()))
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MS)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub RetrieveImage()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SmallDBConnection)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Sales.Customer Where CustomerID = 2", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                txtName.Text = dr("CustomerName").ToString
                txtName.Tag = dr("Picture")
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```